# Word to explain "the exact required quantity" neither too much nor too little

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English a quantity of something that is exactly as much as needed, neither more, nor less.

For example: going into details exactly as much as it is needed, not more, not less...

Comment: When a witness is being sworn in, he affirms that he will tell "the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth." If only truth were quantifiable...

Comment: Your question makes it sounds like the quantity is tangible and measurable, such as "2 liters of gas" or "1 cup of white flour." In these cases, one might say (for a fluid) "2 liters, to the drop"; or (for a dry measure used in cooking) "a level cup." But your example is centered around details, which are not measurable, quantifiable, or exact. In particular, one man's scant narrative may be another man's TMI (Too Much Information).

Comment: Some context would help us to narrow down the meaning you want. Rather than simply defining the term, please can you give a sample sentence with a blank where the word would go?

Answer (score 5):

I think the adjective *[Goldilocks](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Goldilocks)* may fit your criteria

> [AS MODIFIER] Denoting or referring to the most desirable or advantageous part of a range of values or conditions (typically the center):
>
> *the planet is in the middle of what astronomers call the Goldilocks zone: a place that’s not too hot and not too cold*
>
> *he promises us a return to the Goldilocks economy—not too much deflation, not too much inflation*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The term derives from the fairytale about a little girl named [Goldilocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_and_the_Three_Bears) and her encounter with three bears. The modern versions recount a girl who breaks and enters a home and keeps sampling the possessions of the mother, the father and the child, choosing, for example, a bed which is not too soft, not too hard, but just right.

The term has now been adopted into a phenomenon often referred to as the *[Goldilocks principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_principle)* and the *Goldilocks effect*

> The Goldilocks principle states that something must fall within certain margins, as opposed to reaching extremes. When the effects of the principle are observed, it is known as the Goldilocks effect.

Answer (score 1):

"going into details **precisely** as much as it is needed, not more, not less..."

> [**precisely**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=precisely+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=precisely+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.2.2064466...........0.QMVYQyKAc4I&gws_rd=ssl) *adverb*: exactly (used to emphasize the complete accuracy or truth of a statement). "at 2:00 precisely, the phone rang" (Google)

Or perhaps, **proportional** (or both combined),

e.g., going into details which are **precisely** **proportional** to the need, not more, not less...

> [**proportional**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=hss&oq=proportional&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=proportional+definition&gs_l=hp..3.0l5.0.0.3.1276074...........0.2EtNMbc2OiE&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: corresponding in size or amount to something else. (Google)

Comment: Doesn't OP require a synonym for 'exactly as much as ... is needed' rather than for 'exactly'?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - maybe, as in **proportional**?

Comment: I can only think of _consummation_ or _realisation_, but I'd not choose these over _exact amount needed_.  _Optimum_ as a noun is less rarefied, but means _best conditions possible_.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean @Edwin Ashworth, in any case, I find myself rather committed to this course upon which I find myself. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The neatest answer, usually lower case, is

**[q. s.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_satis)**

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

A **sufficiency** is defined by oxforddictionaries.com as "an adequate amount of something".

Comment: But that doesn't mean "exactly as much as needed", it means "at least as much as needed". A *bare sufficiency* is exactly as much as needed.

Answer (score 0):

> [***Lagom***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagom) is a Swedish word meaning "just the right amount". [...] The Lexin Swedish-English dictionary defines lagom as "enough, sufficient, adequate, just right". Lagom is also widely translated as "in moderation", "in balance", "perfect-simple", and "suitable" (in matter of amounts). Whereas words like "sufficient" and "average" suggest some degree of abstinence, scarcity, or failure, lagom carries the connotation of appropriateness, although not necessarily perfection.

Considering the failed efforts to translate *lagom* into English, you might be better off borrowing the Swedish word.

Answer (score 0):

**succinct** —Dictionary definitions don't support the spirit of this usage, so I turned to Wiki.

> In computer science, a succinct data structure is a data structure which uses an amount of space that is "close" to the information-theoretic lower bound, but (unlike other compressed representations) still allows for efficient query operations. -[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure)

Succinct is as small as it can get without losing functionality. Any smaller and it's called *compact*; larger and it's *implicit*.

Examples:

There is a *succinct amount* of table salt that goes into making chocolate chip cookies. Any less and they taste like cardboard; too much and they taste salty.

Please give me only the *succinct* details.